# How to create a responsive div in cone shape

Tags: css, css-shapes, clip-path

does anyone knows a way to create a div with responsive width in shape of an inverted cone (see attached code snippet) only using css. Also this div needs to have a repeated background image (pattern).

I tried to use clipPath:

```css
#div {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 90px, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
 clip-path: polygon(50% 25%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
background: blue;
  padding-top: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

This works fine in Safari and Chrome but won't work in Mozilla, Opera or IE.
Is there a way to achieve for all relevant browsers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Nit I can't figure out a way, to treat a SVG polygon to be fully responsive in height and width, containing child elements and having a repeated background image.

Answer (score 2):

Use `linear-gradient` with *side* or *corner* values instead of fixed angles. You can make that shape with transforms too, but that'll require JS to make it responsive.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnynsswh/)**

```css
body {
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
div:after, div:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    height: inherit;
    width: 50%;
}
div:before {
    left: 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom left, white 50%, transparent 50%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom left, white 50%, transparent 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom left, white 50%, transparent 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}
div:after {
    right: 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom right, white 50%, transparent 50%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom right, white 50%, transparent 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom right, white 50%, transparent 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, that seems to work fine. But i still need to be able to set a repeated background-image for the div instead of setting its background to white. It seems like, there is no way to add repeated images in "linear-gradient".

Answer (score 0):

You can set the div to have overflow hidden, and then set 2 pseudo elements with skew, one for each half

```css
.test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.test:after, .test:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.test:before {
  left: 0px;
  transform: skewY(15deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-15deg, white 0px, lightblue 40px);

}
.test:after {
    right: 0px;
  transform: skewY(-15deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(15deg, white 0px, lightblue 40px);
  
 }
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```